# Is it mandatory to post screenshots to support your answer?

Tags: discussion

For questions which ask about when a specific event happens, pointing out the anime episode number or the manga chapter number adequately answers the question. Is that sufficient, or is it also *mandatory* to post screenshots?

Example:

> **Q.** In which episode was Naruto born? 
>   **A.** Naruto was born in episode 1.

Does the below image really add anything more to the answer?
[image: Naruto is born.]

Comment: For your example question, I think that the screenshot adds nothing besides page load time. (Is this post a reaction to people asking you to add screenshots to your answers or something?)

Comment: @senshin: This answer was what triggered this meta post: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/18910/when-did-naruto-learn-how-to-generate-a-rasengan-unassisted/217610.

Comment: (By the way, that answer got -1 around when I edited the post, and I only posted the first comment 10 minutes later. I didn't vote on that answer, since it may well be a valid answer. I suggested the OP to include a screenshot, so that people can see the scene without having to grab the video and watch it again)

Comment: @nhahtdh Your comment did trigger this question, however, from your comment there, it was obvious (to me, at least) that you weren't implying this should be made mandatory, but you only suggested it would be helpful to add a picture. However, that led me to think about it some more and realize that it is not always obvious if one should post a screenshot or not, so I asked this question for the community to refer to in future.

Comment: As well, my instinct told me that you were not the downvoter. This question is not for questioning your comment at all, but to establish a guideline for the community. Just thought I should make it clear for the readers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Definitely not. However, sometimes screenshots can help the asker visually confirm the accuracy of the answer. For example - answering an [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) question with an image of a character they remember

I do think the community likes putting images into answers, so it may seem like they're compulsory, but they certainly aren't.

---

On a side note, there's been lots of studies that blog posts and such keep readers attention longer if images are included to break the content up. So, I think there's probably a small correlation between getting upvoted more on your answers (because they're more often fully read) and having including images.

[image]

Comment: My most-upvoted question and answer, which are both http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/13076/7579, are also the ones with the most pictures in them.